# Can I publish Java package "com.my_company.xxxxx" if my_company is not exist yet?

Tags: java, maven

Can I publish Java package "com.my_company.xxxxx" if  my_company, therefore website `my_company.com` is not exist yet?

Comment: The namespace of your API is unrelated to your company domain, and in fact using domain names for packages is only a "recommendation" there are no restrictions to the names you choose (a domain name is convenient and hopefully prevents collisions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but if you don't control my_company.com, you're running the risk that someone else might register that domain and publish conflicting packages, although that's improbable. It's probably best to make sure you have the domain first, which is relatively inexpensive.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.  The choice of package name is a convention, not a technical requirement.  The package naming convention is designed to avoid / minimize accidental package name collisions due to two groups choosing the same package name.

This only becomes a *technical* problem in the following circumstances:

- If someone else tries to mix Java code from both sources they could run into problems due to either collisions of fully qualified names, ambiguous wild-card imports, or other more obscure things.
- You *may* not be permitted to publish your code to Maven Central using a package name or Maven artifact identifier that doesn't follow accepted conventions.  (I am not sure about this.  But if it is permitted, it is a bad idea.  Especially if you use a misleading artifact identifier.)

Is it advisable?

Probably not.  The risk of actual collisions is vanishingly small.  However, if you do pick something that someone else is legitimately using, AND you publish your code, then you may be forced to change your package names ... or risk expensive legal action under Trademark law.

This is a much more significant problem than hypothetical package name conflicts.

How to avoid it?

1. Register the (proposed) company domain name first.  Registering a domain name is relatively cheap, and that is one of the first things you will need to do when forming the company.
2. Register a DNS name that corresponds to your product rather than your company.
3. Use the name of (say) your Github repository name as the prefix package; e.g.

   ```
    com.github.myname.myrepo
   ```

   That should be sufficiently unique.

Note: in all of the above you need to choose a company and/or product name that *won't* get you into trouble with trademarks.

Comment: Exhaustive answer! Thank you for you time.